# How to use LEFT and RIGHT keyword in SPARK SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark SQL,

In MS SQL, we have LEFT keyword, `LEFT(Columnname,1) in('D','A') then 1 else 0`.

How to implement the same in SPARK SQL.

Comment: If you are using JDBC to a MS SQL server, then you can run the exact same statement

Comment: I am reading data from Parquet table from Azure, I want to know how LEFT keyword in SPARK SQL @cricket_007

Answer (score 16):

You can use `substring` function with positive `pos` to take from the left:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.substring

substring(column, 0, 1)
```

and negative `pos` to take from the right:

```
substring(column, -1, 1)
```

So in Scala you can define

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.substring

def left(col: Column, n: Int) = {
  assert(n >= 0)
  substring(col, 0, n)
}

def right(col: Column, n: Int) = {
  assert(n >= 0)
  substring(col, -n, n)
}

val df = Seq("foobar").toDF("str")

df.select(
  Seq(left _, right _).flatMap(f => (1 to 3).map(i => f($"str", i))): _*
).show
```

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|substring(str, 0, 1)|substring(str, 0, 2)|substring(str, 0, 3)|substring(str, -1, 1)|substring(str, -2, 2)|substring(str, -3, 3)|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|                   f|                  fo|                 foo|                    r|                   ar|                  bar|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Similarly in Python:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring
from pyspark.sql.column import Column

def left(col, n):
    assert isinstance(col, (Column, str))
    assert isinstance(n, int) and n >= 0
    return substring(col, 0, n)

def right(col, n):
    assert isinstance(col, (Column, str))
    assert isinstance(n, int) and n >= 0
    return substring(col, -n, n)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

Use `substring(column, 0, 1)` instead of `LEFT` function.

where

- 0 : starting position in the string
- 1 : Number of characters to be selected

Example : Consider a LEFT function :

```
LEFT(upper(SKU),2)
```

Corresponding SparkSQL statement would be :

```
substring(upper(SKU),1,2)
```

Answer (score 4):

To build upon user6910411's answer, you can also use isin and then to build a new column with the result of your character comparison.

Final full code would look something like this

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.select(substring($"Columnname", 0, 1) as "ch")
    .withColumn("result", when($"ch".isin("D", "A"), 1).otherwise(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are Spark SQL `right` and `left` functions as of Spark 2.3

Suppose you have the following DataFrame.

```
+----------------------+
|some_string           |
+----------------------+
|this 23 has 44 numbers|
|no numbers            |
|null                  |
+----------------------+
```

Here's how to get the leftmost two elements using the SQL `left` function:

```scala
df.select(expr("left(some_string, 2)").as("left_two")).show(false)
```

```
+--------+
|left_two|
+--------+
|th      |
|no      |
|null    |
+--------+
```

Passing in SQL strings to `expr()` isn't ideal.  Scala API users don't want to deal with SQL string formatting.

I created a library called [bebe](https://github.com/MrPowers/bebe) that provides easy access to the left function:

```scala
df.select(bebe_left(col("some_string"), lit(2)).as("left_two")).show()
```

```
+--------+
|left_two|
+--------+
|th      |
|no      |
|null    |
+--------+
```

The Spark SQL `right` and `bebe_right` functions work in a similar manner.

You can use the Spark SQL functions with the `expr` hack, but it's better to use the bebe functions that are more flexible and type safe.