# LEFT and In Function - PySpark SQL

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert the below SQL query in PySpark but somehow it is not working.

```html
SELECT 
          Distinct *
                  FROM Dataset 
                  where left(PAT,3) in ('123','203')
```

I have converted the query in pySpark indicated below

```html
   df_data=PAT_Data

   df_data.where(df_data.PAT.substr(1,3)='123').show
   
   OR
   
   df_data.filter(col("PAT").like("123%")).show()
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use LEFT and RIGHT keyword in SPARK SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40136922/how-to-use-left-and-right-keyword-in-spark-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isin` operator after taking the substring of the `PAT` column:

```
df_data = spark.createDataFrame([['123221'], ['2321'], ['123221'], ['20322']], ['PAT'])
df_data.show()
+------+
|   PAT|
+------+
|123221|
|  2321|
|123221|
| 20322|
+------+

df_data.where(df_data.PAT.substr(1,3).isin(['123', '203'])).show()
+------+
|   PAT|
+------+
|123221|
|123221|
| 20322|
+------+
```

To drop duplicates:

```
df_data.where(df_data.PAT.substr(1,3).isin(['123', '203'])).dropDuplicates().show()
+------+
|   PAT|
+------+
| 20322|
|123221|
+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

check if the following works for you:

```
df_data.where('PAT like "123%"').show()

df_data.where('PAT rlike "^(123|203)"').distinct().show()

df_data.where('substr(PAT,1,3) in (123,203)').distinct().show()
```

btw. tested on spark.sparkContext.version = '2.2.1'